# Does Android Studio emulator affect Firestore login?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

My app is not automatically logging in when I restart the Android emulator. I believe previously it was doing so - though this might have been a bug caused by some bad code I have since ironed out. So to troubleshoot this problem I first need to discover whether or not this is simply a feature of the emulator.

Here is my code. I've confirmed that it successfully logs into FirebaseAuth and creates a user. According to documentation, automatically logging in on reboot should be as easy as this:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null)
        firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator has no bearing on the way Firebase Auth actually works.  The problem is almost certainly that you're asking the SDK if the user is signed in before the SDK is certain about that.  Instead of calling `auth.getCurrentUser()` you should use an [auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) to get a callback when the final authentication state of the user is known.  It might not be known immediately at launch, as the user's token might have expired and need to be refreshed at the server.  This takes time.

Your app should wait until this auth state listener indicates that the user is actually signed.  This means that your listener will actually be the thing to move your UI along to do things like make queries and present data to the user.